# Should breadcrumbs follow URL structure?

Tags: seo, e-commerce, friendly-url

From what I understand, the closer a page is to the root the better it is for SEO. So something like `http://mystore.com/book1` has more SEO authority over `http://mystore.com/cat1/author1/book1` given that there's no requirement to keep `cat1` in the url.

If I were to flatten my store's URL to `http://mystore.com/book1`, should I also reflect this in the breadcrumb so that it no longer follows `cat1 > author1 > book1`?

Note that I want to keep the page `http://mystore.com/cat1` and even `http://mystore.com/cat1/author1` (or an alternative `http://mystore.com/author1`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For seo it's better flatten urls such as http://mystore.com/book1, and there is no problems with breadcrumbs that follows cat1 > author1 > book1 (search engines not so smart to determine breadcrumbs on site), but if breadcrumbs are links so for seo would be better cat1 > author1 > book1 then just one link book1.

PS: I think that breadcrumbs are for real people more needed then for seo :)

Comment: I'll be using breadcrumb schemas to help guide search engines. So, I guess I'll just link (from the breadcrumb) `cat1` to `http://mystore.com/cat1` and `author1` to `http://mystore.com/author1` then, making sure to use the canonical tag.

Comment: **Where is the evidence to suggest that flattening URLs is better for SEO?**